# sudo apt-get update makes the wifi connection crash

Tags: wireless

When I run sudo apt-get update, I got the following output

```
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en 
Hit http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en 
59% [Connecting to fr.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.23)]
```

And it got stuck at this last line because it makes the wifi crash. Ubuntu is still connected to my SSID but internet doesn't work anymore. Even disconnected and reconnected the wifi doesn't help and I have to do a full reboot of the system to have internet working again.